# Repeat in cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am doing load test right now and need to create 14000 tickets to see how app will response.

My question is about how to repeat simple auto test, until I get 14 000 ticket registration.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

Cypress._.times(1000, ()=>{

const timestamp = new Date().getTime();  

describe('Load', ()=>{


    it('Loadtest', ()=>{
    
    cy.visit('link')// visit site
    cy.get('#email').type('name')//insert username
    cy.get('#password').type('password')//insert password
    cy.get('._btn_1wzi7_1').click() //click login button 
    cy.get('.css-19bb58m').type('Microsoft Outlook 2').type('{enter}')
    cy.get('#title').type(`Random Text ${timestamp}`)
    cy.get('#note').type(`Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} 
    Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp}
    Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp} Another Random Text ${timestamp}`)
    cy.get('#checkbox').click() //press check box which should be pressed
    cy.get('._btn_1wzi7_1').click()//
    cy.get('._title_1jitq_37').should('have.text', '10000') //this number is the id of created ticket and it increments after each created ticket.       

   
    })
      
})

})`
```

Right now it repeats that test 1000 times and when I make it 2000 it works slower.

I need it repeated when this `cy.get('._title_1jitq_37').should('have.text', '10000')` become to 24000.

Comment: This approach would be creating a ticket 1000 times serially, not simultaneously. It might be easier to use a tool dedicated to load testing.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looping 14_000 times in your test, try it with [cypress-grep](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/burning-tests/) burn parameter.

For example

```js
npx cypress run --env burn=5 --spec cypress/integration/A.js
```

I haven't tried it with that many iterations, so can't say it will be quicker, but the way you have tried generates a very large spec that must be parsed into a queue and stored in memory.

As I understand it, cypress-grep controls the burn from the Cypress node (background) process so the memory footprint is likely to be smaller.

Ref: [Current home page](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/grep) with install instructions and usage details.